# Why does the compilation results in a missing template arguments error?

Tags: c++, templates

I wish to use a Spring class with a template parameter V:

```
#include "Spring.hpp"
template <typename K, typename L>
    struct spring_value {
        K spring_constant;
        L spring_length;
};

typedef Spring<std::vector<spring_value<double, double>>> Spring;
typedef Spring::value value;   // why struct Force does not see this? 

struct Force {
    value v = {1.0, 2.0};   // error
    spring_value<double,double> v = {1.0, 2.0};   // ok, but ...
    double s = v.spring_value;   // also error

}
```

Spring class:

```
template <typename V>               
class Spring {

public:
 typedef V value;       

}
```

However, the program produces a `missing template arguments before 'v'` error. Why doesn't `struct Force` sees `spring value` or `value` in Spring class?

Comment: Can you produce a small, *complete* program that produces this error?

Comment: The second error is because you can't assign a struct to a double.

Comment: Actually that's wrong - the second error is because v is already a spring_value, and you are trying to get a member of v that's also called spring value. At least from the code you posted. Is that a typo?

Comment: shouldn't it be template <class V> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't even compile:

```
typedef Spring<spring_value<double, double>> Spring;
```

You can't have two types with the same name!

Rename the template to something like `Spring_`, or give it a default template argument.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question's already been answered, but ...

This doesn't compile for me (your original code):

```
struct Force {
  value v = {1.0, 2.0}; //error
}
```

but this does:

```
struct Force {
  value v = {{1.0, 2.0}};
}
```

`v` is a vector of structs. The second version initializes the vector `v` with a single element, which is itself initialized with the values `{1.0, 2.0}`.

Comment: I also realized it. Thanks!